# Why does division in #define cause division in code to output a different answer

Tags: arduino

I was getting speed values 4 times less than I calculated and narrowed it down to the division of the inverse of the wheel radius. I originally had `WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO` and when doing the reciprocal I was getting an incorrect answer(a factor of 4 difference). I have replicated the problem in the code below.

Hardware is an Arduino UNO.

```
#define WHEEL_RADIUS 30.0
#define WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO 60.0 / 2.0

void setup() { Serial.begin(115200); }

void loop() {
  Serial.println("WHEEL_RADIUS : " + String(WHEEL_RADIUS, 8));
  Serial.println("Inverse WHEEL_RADIUS : " + String(1.000 / WHEEL_RADIUS, 8));
  Serial.println("WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO : " + String(WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO, 8));
  Serial.println("Inverse WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO : " +
                 String(1.000 / WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO, 8));
  delay(1000);
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
WHEEL_RADIUS : 30.00000000
Inverse WHEEL_RADIUS : 0.03333334
WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO : 30.00000000
Inverse WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO : 0.00833333
```

`Inverse WHEEL_RADIUS` is correct using a calculator. Most problems I searched for were for integer division which I think I am avoiding here. I know the current workaround but I would like to know what I am fundamentally missing from this example that is giving me different answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are simply textual substitutions. Your `WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO` is defined as

```
#define WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO 60.0 / 2.0
```

which means that

```
1.000 / WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO
```

expands into

```
1.000 / 60.0 / 2.0
```

Since `/` operator in C and C++ associates left-to-right, this is interpreted as

```
(1.000 / 60.0) / 2.0
```

Obviously, this is not even remotely the same as

```
 1.000 / WHEEL_RADIUS
```

(which is apparently what you expected).

This is why when you define macros as expressions, it is important to remember to parenthesize them

```
#define WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO (60.0 / 2.0)
```

This will save you from such surprises.

An even better idea (at least in C++) would be to use `const` variables instead of macros and forget about this problem entirely

```
const double WHEEL_D_OVER_TWO = 60.0 / 2.0;
```